# Stripping whitespace out of smarty templates from PHP

Tags: php, html, smarty

Is there a way to tell Smarty from PHP that you want it to strip all the whitespace in your templates before sending to browser, as if all your templates were embedded in {strip} tags? Some sort of Smarty object parameter or something?

Answer (score 2):

In your Smarty plugin folder there is a filter that can be easily adapted to the task: it's `outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php`.

Just add the line

```
$source = preg_replace("`\s+`ms", " ", $source);
```

(from the forum post linked by Martin) at line 51 and then call the output filter.

The advantage is that said filter does a nice job of saving and then restoring the code blocks where you might want to leave whitespace alone - inside **script**, **pre** and **textarea** elements (I'dd add the **code** element to the list, too).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most recent implementation of the trimWhitespace output filter from smarty 3.1 which seems to do what you want.

raw file: http://smarty-php.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4136/branches/Smarty_3_1_cleanup/distribution/libs/plugins/outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php

source browser: http://code.google.com/p/smarty-php/source/browse/branches/Smarty_3_1_cleanup/distribution/libs/plugins/outputfilter.trimwhitespace.php?r=4136

Answer (score 0):

You could create and register an [output filter](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/plugins.outputfilters.php) to do this; in the output filter, you can use for example [this function](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3361456.htm) to strip out unneeded whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another output filter to strip white space.

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25&sid=26a10d55ac90d50dca7914e33fdc6fa1