# How to get rid of whitespace in Smarty {block}s?

Tags: php, templates, smarty, removing-whitespace

I've run into a problem where defining the value of a `{block}` introduces a lot of unnecessary whitespace.

I've a main template, let's call it `main.html`, which looks like this (simplified):

```
<html>
<title>{block name=title}{$default_title}{/block}</title>
...
</html>
```

Then I inherit from it in let's say `topics.html`, and I define the title block in it:

```
{extends file="main.html"}

{block title}
{if $topic}
  {if $topic == "all"}
    {eval $Config['titles']['topics']['all']}
  {else}
    {eval $Config['titles']['topics']['particular']}
  {/if}
{else}
  {eval $Config['titles']['topics']['list']}
{/if}
{/block}
```

Now when I compile the `topics.html` template, there is so much whitespace inside of `<title>...</title>` tag.

For example, it looks like this:

```
<title>
    Showing all wiki topics  </title>
```

How could I trim/strip the whitespace from the result of evaluating a block so it looked like the following:?

```
<title>Showing all wiki topics</title>
```

I tried adding `{strip}...{/strip}` around the `{block title}...{/block}` like this:

```
{strip}
{block title}
...
{/block}
{/strip}
```

But that didn't change anything.

I also tried this:

```
{block title|strip}
...
{/block}
```

But that was a syntax error. I also tried this:

```
{block title|trim}
...
{/block}
```

But it also was a syntax error.

I also tried:

```
{block title}
{strip}
...
{/strip}
{/block}
```

But that didn't help either as I already introduced a new-line after `{block title}`so it stays there in the compiled template.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: It seems that somebody else has had the same problem, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207163/remove-extra-html-spaces-in-smarty

Comment: I'm surprised `{strip}{block title}...` didn't work, are you sure?

Comment: @WesleyMurch That doesn't work. See answer below by rodney.

Answer (score 2):

As of Smarty 3.1 you cannot wrap `{block}`s in other constructs. (This might change with Smarty 3.2)
Have you tried putting the `{strip}` tags inside the `{block}s`? Otherwise have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9207456/515124)

Comment: I tried putting `{strip}` right after `{block}` without a newline after the `{block}` and it worked, but it doesn't look too nice. :) Also I tried putting ifs/elses outside, and blocks within ifs/elses, but smarty didn't like that.

Comment: As I said, `{block}`s cannot be wrapped in anything right now…